# Определить viewBox для svg, если в самом svg он отсутствует

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg

Есть два svg.

В первом случае у svg есть заданный viewBox="0 0 57.21 126.47"
https://jsfiddle.net/5jaLdyex/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 57.21 126.47">...
```

Во втором случае у svg viewBox удален. В остальном svg без изменений.
https://jsfiddle.net/5jaLdyex/1/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...
```

width/height тоже отсутствуют и в первом случае, и во втором.

Вопрос: как определить пропорции для svg #2? Точно знаю, что это возможно сделать, потому что если загрузить этот svg в конструктор canva, то он определит размер 57.21 126.47 даже если не задано width/height/viewBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения `wdth` `height` можно узнать использовав метод JS `getBBox()`

```
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const {x, y, width, height} = svg.getBBox();
console.log(width);
```

Вы можете установить значение параметров viewBox равными высоте и ширине пользовательского окна просмотра (viewport)

```
<script>
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const {x, y, width, height} = svg.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `${x} ${y} ${width} ${height}`); 
</script>
```

Значения будут те же, как в вашем первом примере `viewBox="0 0 57.21 126.47"`
Именно так и нарисовано ваше изображение в векторном редакторе.

Чтобы уменьшить его, например в 10 раз, нужно в шапке svg увеличить viewBox в 10 раз `viewBox="0 0 572.1 1264.7"`
или с помощью JS

```
<script>
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const {x, y, width, height} = svg.getBBox();
<!-- Увеличиваем viewBox - уменьшаем изображение -->
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `${x} ${y} ${width * 10} ${height * 10}`);
</script>
```

**Другой путь для регулировки размеров SVG**

Раз вы уже знаете размер `viewBox="0 0 57.21 126.47"` укажите его явно, не указывая width, height в шапке SVG.
Оберните SVG в div и укажите width, height в относительных единицах

```
<style>
.container {
width:10vw;
height:10vh;
}
<div class="container"> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 57.21 126.47">
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А если говорить про серверное решение? Чтобы getBBox дал результат отличный от нуля, надо чтобы svg обязательно было отображено в документе. Как я понимаю, если этот код запустить со стороны того же nodejs, то будет возвращено 0 0. 

"Другой путь для регулировки размеров SVG" - это не то, что нужно. Пользователь загружает svg произвольное без width, без height, без viewBox. Вот нужно узнать его ширину и высоту. И, конечно, хотелось бы это сделать со стороны сервера.

Comment: @Floyat там даже просто опытным путём чисто по координатам видно что viewbox равен `0 0 59 126`

Comment: @MaximLensky исходный viewBox 0 0 57.21 126.47, а не 0 0 78 126. И что за опытный путь? Речь про абсолютно любое svg изображение без viewBox, width, height и с любым количеством path внутри. Со стороны клиента - getBBox работает. Но это не самое удобное решение, которое работает только с видимыми svg в документе.

Comment: Нашёл серверное решение со стороны PHP:
$img = new imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($raw);
$img->trimImage (0);
$dimension = $img->getImageGeometry();

в $dimension будет нужная ширина и высота.

Answer (score 0):

https://svgwg.org/specs/integration/#svg-css-sizing

Если нет width/height/viewBox, то размер SVG будет 300×150px независимо от содержимого.

Comment: Если загрузить svg #2 в конструктор (canva.com), то они задают вот такие размеры для svg:

width="57.266632080078125" height="126.50769805908203" viewBox="0.000884773675352335 -0.017702089622616768 57.266632080078125 126.50769805908203"

То есть они определили точные размеры без ширины, без высоты и viewBox. Вот пытаюсь понять хотя бы примерный алгоритм для этого. 

Причём тут 300х150?